# Netty ChannelUpstreamHandler and HTTP pipelining

Tags: http, netty, pipelining

I was playing with the Netty example `org.jboss.netty.example.http.snoop` and I noticed that
Firefox does 4 requests leading to the creation of 4 `HttpRequestHandler` instances and Internet Explorer 8/9 does 2 request leading to the creation of 2 `HttpRequestHandler` instances.

I think this is due to the HTTP 1.1 pipelining, however even after changing the `network.http.pipelining.*` keys for FireFox and the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` registry entries for IE, Netty behaves the same way.

My question is, is this expected and correct or am I missing something and is it possible to configure Netty to drop subsequent idempotent requests or this has to be implemented by the `HttpRequestHandler` eventually?

Answer (score 1):

You should print out the path to find out what FF is requesting. I am pretty sure it is favicon.ico which is requested multiple times (retry mechanism) because of invalid format being sent by Snoop example.

edit. I verified it, and it is indeed favicon which is requested three times:

```
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - [id: 0x57c52e72, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63056 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080] RECEIVED: DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false) GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - GET
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - /

Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - [id: 0x57c52e72, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63056 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080] RECEIVED: DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false) GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0 Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - GET
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - /favicon.ico

Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - [id: 0x57c52e72, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63056 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080] RECEIVED: DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false) GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - GET
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - /favicon.ico

Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - [id: 0x57c52e72, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63056 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080] RECEIVED: DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false) GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - GET
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] - /favicon.ico
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in FF, since FF is requesting the favicon with Accept-hreader set to text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml in the last two requests. Does anybody have more info?

Comment: Japer - confirmed; weird indeed, FF is asking 3 times for the favicon, Chrome and IE are happy with a single favicon request :).